# SlidingTabStrip scroll bar indicator not Showing underneath Tabs API<21

Tags: android, slidingmenu, sliding

I am using [SlidingTabLayout.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) from `github/google/iosched` i.e Latest File.

When I run my application on android `Lollipop` it show an indicator below the selected(focused) tab, but for `API<21`  indicator is not shown. I am goggling it for 2 days now. Didn't find any solution?
Any help would be much appreciated.